# How to change answer depending on answer in Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

im developing web application on Laravel&Livewire and faced with problem, that cant solve, so please help me out.

THE IDEA: There's initial question with **ID = 1**. and if user clicks on YES button, question should change to **ID = 2**, if user clicks on No button question should change to **ID = 3**. So based on this logic there are more than 200 questions.

LIVEWIRE CONTROLLER:

```
use App\Models\Question;
use Livewire\Component;

class Pain extends Component
{
    public $question;
    public $current_question;
    public $answer;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->current_question = Question::where('id', 1)->get();
    }

    public function answerChoice($choice)
    {
        $this->answer = $choice;

        if ($this->answer != 0) {
            $this->question = Question::where('id', 2)->get();
        } else {
            $this->question = Question::where('id', 3)->get();
        }
        $this->reset('current_question', 'answer');

        $this->current_question = $this->question;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.quiz.man.eyes.pain');
    }
}
```

LIVEWIRE BLADE FILE:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        @foreach($current_question as $question)
        <h3>{{ $question->question_explanation }}</h3>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="align-content-center">
        <div>
            <button wire:click="answerChoice('1')" class="btn btn-outline-success">Yes</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button wire:click="answerChoice('0')" class="btn btn-outline-danger">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PROBLEM: In the code written above, only first 3 questions are working. Here's how it is supposed to work. User clicked YES, and question with **ID = 1** changed to **ID = 2**, then clicked NO, and question changed to **ID = 5**, then again cliked on YES and question changed to **ID = 12**. But in my code only works first 3 questions

Comment: You code only check the answer and return question ID 2 or 3. You have to add addtionnal logic to also check the current question ID to go further.

Comment: Okay, how can i do that, is there any examples, pls

Comment: In your if/else statement, for example if you clicked yes and the current question is ID 5, then return question ID 12, etc. If you have a lot of question it may be a good idea to store, for example, the next question ID by answers "yes", "no" in your database to have less code to write, but that is your job :)

Comment: What is the logic of yes and no? how do you decide which question to show on button click sometimes you skip 3 sometimes 6 questions?

Comment: @A.Z there's already been decided which question comes after others depending on the answer

Comment: @YannickBeuchat Oh that's also a good point, I'll keep it on my mind, thank you